# Wordpress Permalink Issue Apache (index.php)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have tried almost everything online however am not able to solve this issue. I just shifted my Wordpress website to Azure. The permalinks are not working now.

The following options in `apache2.conf` are on:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The following is my `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The module rewrite is also enabled.

```
/var/www/html$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

**I can access the files only with index.php between the page & website url**

```
http://www.indiafastener.com/index.php/archives/1434 -- Works fine
```

The above will work however,

```
http://www.indiafastener.com/archives/1434 -- Returns 404
```

Comment: Go to your wordpress panel and change your website URL or do it in the database.

Comment: Url has already been updated through db